# Comparando string no php

Tags: php

Gostaria de sabe como faço para comparar o conteúdo de uma string no PHP.
Estou procurando uma palavra em uma linha, mas não sei em qual posição que ela se encontra.

```
$ch_atend
if($linha == "idle") { $ch_atend = $ch_atend++; };
```

Esse código esta dentro de um *While* e a finalidade é percorrer linha a linha para contar quantas vezes aparece a palavra *IDLE*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei exatamente de onde vem o seu `$linha` mas vejo duas opções. Ou compara como está a fazer, e aí só dá verdadeiro se `$linha` tiver exatamente os caracteres `idle``;

ou então procura a sequência de letras com uma RegEx.

**Mas atênção:** a sua variável `$ch_atend` deve ser atribuída `0` fora do `while`.

Opção 1:

```
$ch_atend = 0;
while(<condição>){
    if($linha == "idle") { $ch_atend = $ch_atend++; };
```

Opção 2

```
$ch_atend = 0;
while(<condição>){
    if(preg_match('/idle/', $linha )) { $ch_atend = $ch_atend++; };
```

Comment: [`stripos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) em vez da expressão regular também serviria.

Comment: A opção 1 está igualzinha o que eu tinha colocado, conforme pode ver na abertura da pergunta.  A Opção 2 eu testei da mesma forma e não funcionou.
Os dois textos estão em minusculo e retorna zero.
Não sei o que fazer.  
Obrigado.

Comment: Fiz o teste apenas com o substr_count e outro arquivo e funcionou normalmente.
Pelo que estou entendo, a variavel $linha esta sempre passando zero.
Preciso de ajuda.

Comment: Estou sozinho no forum.
Consegui com preg_match.
Por algum motivo, não funcionou com $ch_atend = $ch_atend++;
$ch_atend = $atend + 1;

Comment: Sérgio. O meu $linha é a variavel que percorre linha a linha de um arquivo texto.

Answer (score 4):

O PHP já possui uma função pronta para contar ocorrências de substrings numa strings, [`substr_count`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.substr-count.php). Com isso, o loop linha a linha nem é necessário. O uso é assim:

```
$texto = "um texto grande ... \n multilinha ... \n sei lá mais o que ...";
$ocorrencias = substr_count($texto, '...');
echo $ocorrencias; // 3
```

Comment: Bom dia.  <br/>  
Eu tentei da seguinte forma e retornou 0 e o arquivo tem uma palavra idle.<br> '<?php $arquivo = fopen("agentes.txt", "r"); if($arquivo == false) { print "Não foi possível abrir o arquivo"; } $ch_atend = 0; while(true) { $linha = fgets($arquivo); if($linha==NULL) { break; } echo $linha."<br />"; } $cont_idle = substr_count($linha, "idle"); echo $cont_idle; fclose($arquivo); ?>

Comment: No momento que está verificando, a linha é null. Mova a checagem para dentro do loop, ou verifique o arquivo inteiro de uma vez.

Comment: Eu imaginei que era Null, só não sabia o que fazer.
Obrigado.