# Como recuperar a quantidade de caracteres via expressão regular?

Tags: javascript, regex

Como saber a quantidade de caracteres repetidos (exemplo: *Goi**a**b**a*** = 2 letras *a*), caracteres consecutivos (sequencia de letras *abc..*) e números consecutivos (exemplo: *12345..*) dentro de uma palavra, utilizando expressão regular? Isso é possível?

Comment: Exemplo em javascript: `'teste'.match(/e/g).length` retorna 2 pois tem duas letras `E`

Comment: Correto @WallaceMaxters é exatamente isto.

Comment: Eu já tenho algo desse tipo: [Clique Aqui!](http://jsfiddle.net/fs3eu10x/), mais mesmo assim não esta funcionando direito.

Comment: É PHP ou javascript ?

Comment: A função que estou fazendo é em JavaScript.

Comment: Você não vai conseguir fazer isso sem restringir a uma letra específica, como o Wallace fez.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com expressões regulares não deve ser possível fazer isso como citado na [**resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/49123/6454)  do Miguel Angelo, porém, através de um [*loop*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estrutura_de_repeti%C3%A7%C3%A3o) você pode obter a quantidade de ocorrências dos caracteres e armazená-los em um [array associativo](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php).

```
var str = "Goiaba";
var ocorrencias = {};

for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var n = str[i];
    ocorrencias[n] = ocorrencias[n] ? ocorrencias[n] + 1 : 1;
}    
console.log(ocorrencias); // {G=1, o=1, i=1, a=2, b=1}
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yrbuw4yk/)</kbd>

Para deixar mais bonito e organizado faça isso em uma função:

```
function retornarOcorrencias(str){
    var ocorrencias = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        var n = str[i];
        ocorrencias[n] = ocorrencias[n] ? ocorrencias[n] + 1: 1;
    }
    return ocorrencias;
}

var str = 'Goiaba';
var num = '001549954607410';

var strItens = retornarOcorrencias(str); 
var numItens = retornarOcorrencias(num); 

console.log(strItens); // {G=1, o=1, i=1, a=2, b=1}
console.log(numItens); // {0=4, 1=2, 4=3, 5=2, 6=1, 7=1, 9=2}
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2b44pnr0/)</kbd>

Para verificar o número de ocorrências de um caractere em particular:

```
console.log(strItens['a']); // 2
```

Nas respostas abaixo mostra como fazer isso em PHP:

- [**Como retornar palavras mais comuns de um texto com PHP?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22855/como-retornar-palavras-mais-comuns-de-um-texto-com-php)
- [**Comparando string no php**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21680/comparando-string-no-php)

Comment: eu fiz algumas modificações aqui e a função funcionou perfeitamente, agradeço por sanar a minha duvida vlw!.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que não tem jeito de fazer isso com `RegExp`.

Vai ai um JavaScript pra detectar pontos duplicados na sua string.
Vê ai se te serve:

```
function DetectarRepeticoes(str) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var itL = 1; itL <= str.length; itL++) {
        for (var itS = 0; itS <= str.length - itL; itS++) {
            var seq = str.substr(itS, itL);
            obj[seq] = obj.hasOwnProperty(seq) ? obj[seq]+1 : 1;
        }
    }
    var res = {};
    for (var k in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k) && obj[k]>1)
            res[k] = obj[k];
    }
    return res;
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
DetectarRepeticoes("Miguel Angelo Santos Bicudo");
```

Retorno:

```
{
    " ": 3,
    e:   2,
    el:  2,
    g:   2,
    i:   2,
    l:   2,
    n:   2,
    o:   3,
    u:   2
}
```

Nota: este método é de **ordem de n<sup>2</sup>**, onde n é o número de caracteres da string... então não é lá muito eficiente. Mas se for usar com strings pequenas é aceitável... até unas 1000 caracteres acho que ainda fica bom na maioria dos casos.